# whats this pointer in palindrome program i cant get correct result

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int flag=0,length=0;
    char name[30];
    char *p,*q;
    printf("enter the name you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",name);
    p=name;
    q=name;
    while(*p++) length++;
    printf("%d\n",length);
    while((*q++==*--p))
    {
        printf("%c\t%c\n",*q,*p);
        flag=1;
    }
    if(flag==0)
        printf("palindrome\n");
    if(*--q!=*p)
        flag=0; 
    if(flag==1)
        printf("palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("not a palindrome\n");
    return 0;
}
```

see i a checking the strings using pointers i don't know what is the problem
it is some problem in while loop how to solve it 
using the above pointer concept

Comment: again after that i was not getting an answer

Comment: Use `strlen` to calculate length of string .

Comment: Your code is flawed and you, i believe you are not trying to understand why it isn't working!

Comment: its worked if you want i can give you my code   i was trying to understand the concept about the pointers not to show something

Answer (score 1):

Only when all mirrored characters match, is it a palindrome. So the condition after the loop is that p is back at the beginning:

```
while((*q++==*--p) && p>=name)
{
    printf("%c\t%c\n",*q,*p);
}
if (p==name) flag= 1;
if(flag==0)
    printf("not a palindrome\n");
else
    printf("palindrome\n");
```

Comment: You know the `printf` inside loop is not executed .

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to start with strings, please try this:

```
 #include <usual.h>

int main(  )
{
  int flag = 0;
  int length = 0;
  int len2 = 0;
  int i = 0;
  char name[130];
  char p[130];
  char q[130];

  printf( "please enter a name or sentence\n" );
  scanf( "%[^\n]", name );

  length = strlen( name );
  len2 = length;
  strcpy( p, name );
  memset( q, '.', length ); // handy to debug comparaison
  q[length] = '\0';

  for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
  {
    q[--len2] = p[i];
  }

  printf( "\n p==%s", p );
  printf( "\n q==%s", q );
  getchar(  );

  if ( !strcmp( p, q ) )
    flag = 1;

  if ( flag == 1 )
    printf( "\npalindrome\n" );
  else
    printf( "\nnot a palindrome\n" );

  return 0;
}
```